# Link Custom Framework against CocoaPod (statically)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, ios-frameworks

I have a podfile as follows:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
#use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

workspace 'MyWorkspace.xcworkspace'
project 'MyServices/MyServices.xcodeproj'

target 'MyServices' do
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'
end
```

where `MyServices` is a framework project. Everything works fine when I compile the `MyServices` target. However, when `MyServices` framework is imported in my iOS project, I get the error:

```
<Mantle/Mantle.h> file not found.
<AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h> file not found.
```

This happens ONLY when I include the above files in my framework's public header files.

However, if I change my pod file to do `use_frameworks!`, it works perfectly fine even in `MyServices` public headers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target 'MyServices' do
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'Mantle', '~> 2.0'
end
```

try this

Comment: Same error. I guess custom frameworks cannot have pod headers in their public files.

Comment: remove xcworkspace project and lock file try again pod init and pod install